# Hibernate ManyToMany HQL issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My MySql tables:

[db tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8coaZ.jpg)

And My Two Entity Classes are

```
@Entity
public class Tweet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name="tweet_id")
    private int tweetId;
    private String message;
    private Date created;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Person person;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String fullName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "following", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "following_id") })
    private List<Person> following = new ArrayList<Person>();
    ...
}
```

Now I want to display messages of user praveen, and also all the messages mapped to praveen user in the following table. That means praveen user have 2 messages and his following users have 2 messages . Total 4 messages should be displayed. I really don't know how to retrieve this  info using any technique in Hibernate. Please help me

Comment: ok ,first, show us the SQL query that you use for this

Comment: select obj from Tweet t  where t.person.userId=(SELECT pp.following.following_id FROM Person p JOIN p.following pp WHERE pp.userId = 'praveen')";

Comment: Have you managed to load the user `praveen` via JPA? If yes, you have the object and might be able to access its tweets if you extend the `Person` entity with a list of its tweets which is missing in the entities above.

Comment: select * from tweet t where t.user_id =(select following_id from following where following_id=t.user_id) or t.user_id='praveen';   is the native sql im using. Its working fine. But I need HQL

Comment: @Smutje : Yes I am managing via JPA. If I am using get method like  session.get(Person.class,"praveen"); I am getting all  users assigned to praveen using getFollowing method.  But I need tweet messages of praveen user followers as well praveen user own messages. how?

Comment: As I wrote, you could extend the `Person` entity with a list of `Tweet` objects (the information is present anyway) and then access a persons tweets and the following persons tweets, too.

Comment: @Smutje : Thanks  for the response. But extending the classes in Hibernate will disturb my existing classes which was mapped properly ( ID override issues) . So I have tried with following HQL                         from Tweet t where t.person.userId=(select u.userId from  Person u join u.following r where r.userId='praveen'    . But this is giving 0  records

Comment: Why should the classes be disturbed by including (already present) information? That makes no sense at all.